# ILNumerics 3D Contour plots "surface mesh" to "stepping surface mesh" switch?

Tags: ilnumerics

Is there a possibility the display of the 3D contour plots to change?

It should look like this.
[stepping surface mesh](http://www.arction.com/images/screenshots/ultimate/stepping_surface3d.jpg)

I want it to display data points and that's with a full square grid easier than with a distorted grid.
[distorted grid](http://ilnumerics.net/ilcf/41/4910/out.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, but ILNumerics currently does not provide such plots out of the box. However, it helps you significantly to implement it yourself. I suggest, to use an ILTriangles shape to create the grid and surfaces according to your data. See the documentation: http://ilnumerics.net/scene-graph-shapes-and-buffers.html